# SQL Error when passing parameter to API from android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Good day!

**GOAL**

I am attempting to query my database from my mobile app and return the values to my android application of course.

During my initial testing I had no parameters in my query and it was a straight select (Select name from table) and that worked 100% and returned the value to my android application.

**Problem**

Since my connection to my API worked I attempted to edit my code and add my parameters (Select name from table where ID=5). However, this is failing and break points are saying there is an error in my SQL Syntax. I believe the error is with stating my parameter because it works as expected from the browser.

**What I have tried**

The code receives the ID from an intent, and I have tried various ways of formatting the parameter to correct the error but there is no difference.

onCreate Code Snippet showing getting of parameter

```
        idNum= Y.getStringExtra("ID");
       // idNum="'"+idNum+"'"; //attempting to format ID with " 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),licPNum,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        new ActorsAsynTask().execute();



 protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/DAIIS/getNames.php");
                BasicNameValuePair nameid= new BasicNameValuePair("id", idnum);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairList.add(nameid);

                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

                post.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data); //Error here
```

Any help would appriciated

Comment: What string returned from sever in `data` ?

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK 

 Could not look up user information; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 16

But there is no error in my php so im thinking the error is in passing the parameter

Comment: Shoud add `httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` before `httpPost.setEntity(...);`

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works great:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
ArrayList<NameValuePair> inputArguments = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
inputArguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", idnum));
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/DAIIS/getNames.php");
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(inputArguments, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse) client.execute(request);
String data = null;
data = streamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
```

EDIT:

```
private String streamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append((line + "\n"));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Still getting syntax/ parameter error: I placed a break point and 
idnum="2552" (which is correct). and inputArguments shows "id=2552".
Should the 2552 be within quotation marks as well?

Comment: you don't need to add double quotation in front of idnum in webpage.

Comment: Im aware, but, I don't understand why it complains about an SQL error in android and works fine in the webpage unless im doing something parameter related in the android wrong. Once I hard code the parameter in the api and remove it from the application side it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my following code, hope this helps!

```
private HttpResponse makeHTTPRequest(String method, String address, List<NameValuePair> parameters, JSONObject jsonObj, String fromBodyValue)
            throws Exception {
    ...

    if (!address.isEmpty()) {
        address = address.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); // to avoid java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path...

        if ("GET".equals(method)) {
            httpGet = new HttpGet(address);                
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        } else if ("POST".equals(method)) {
            httpPost = new HttpPost(address);                
            if (parameters != null) {
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
            }
            if (jsonObj != null) {     
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), "utf-8"));
            }
            if (fromBodyValue != null) { 
                fromBodyValue = "'" + fromBodyValue + "'";
                StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(fromBodyValue, "utf-8");
                stringEntity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"));
                httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            }
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        }
    }

    return httpResponse;
}
```